# How can I justify it formally?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, computer-science

Given the following algorithm:

```
Function Fun(int n){
int j,k,t=1;
for (j=0; j<=4n^2; j+=4){
     for (k=j; k<=4*sqrt(n); k+=4){
          t+=8;
     }
}
}
```

I want to count how many times the command t+=8; is executed.

I found, by trying several values for n, that it is executed:

[image]

times. But, how can I justify it formally?

Comment: $n$ is not an argument inside your algorithm. Should it be $Fun(int\ n)$? The outer loop should be performed $n^2$ times. How do you get the $\sqrt{n}$ there?

Comment: I thought so, because the inner loop is executed till $j=4 \sqrt{n}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: No, you are right. I did not notice that. Have you tried to keep the $n^2$ in the outer sum, and to use a "positive part" function for the inner loop? I think, then it should be possible to show you claimed formula with induction.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see from the outher cycle, $j$ is a multiple of $4$, so let's call $\;j=4j'$

the inner loop goes from $\;k=j\;$ to $\;k=4\sqrt{n}\;$, whit a skip of $4$, so the number of repetition is 
$$
1+\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor 4\sqrt{n}\rfloor-j}{4}\right\rfloor=1-j'+\left\lfloor\frac{\lfloor 4\sqrt{n}\rfloor}{4}\right\rfloor=1-j'+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor
$$ 
The outer loop goes from $\;j=0\;$ to $\;j=4n^2\;$, with a skip of $4$, so we have 
$$
\sum_{j'=0}^{n^2}1+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-j'
$$
but since $j'$ cannot go over $1+\sqrt{n}$, we have
$$
\sum_{j'=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}1+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-j'
$$
If you want to know the exact number, it is
$$
\sum_{j'=0}^{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor}1+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor-j'=
\left(1+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\right)^2-\frac{\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\left(1+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\right)}{2}
$$
$$
=\frac{\left(2+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\right)\left(1+\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor\right)}{2}
$$

Comment: what does the sum $\displaystyle{ \sum_{j'=0}^{n^2} 1+ \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor-j'}$ represent?

Comment: the total number of repetitions of the inner command t+=8